# Ubuntu 15.04 end Kernel panic - not syncing

Tags: system-installation, bug-reporting

Well i'm pretty new to Linux and i just updated my ubuntu from 14.04 Lts to 14.10 and then to 15.04 there were some errors in the terminal which caught my eyes a little bit too late but i think that was the cause of this problem whenever i try to boot up my computer now it doesn't work anymore it always gives me an error screen with this error [ 5.080309] )--[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! Exit code=0x00007f00
[ 5.080309]

Answer (score 0):

I also have had this problem on 3 occasions. All 3 were while trying to upgrade from 14.04 LTS. Each time the first update and reboot is completed without issue (I assume this is to 14.10). I am then asked to confirm the update to 15.04. I click upgrade and the process begins. During the install I receive a number of errors the last of which suggests the install may be broken. Soon after a notification tells me the installation was successful. A system information check tells me I am now running on 15.04. Everything appears to be working fine except I am unable to continue upgrading to 15.10 or shut down the pc in anyway. Shut down or restart can be selected but nothing happens.
Finally the only remaining option is to manually power off. At this point any reboot will not complete and has the above listed issue displayed on screen.
The only way I have found to correct this issue is to fresh install 15.10. This is frustrating because I would like to upgrade my main PC to 15.10 at some point and I would prefer to not do a fresh install. It seems there is no other safe way though.